# Choose database when logging

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a class to open connection a make everything about SQL

```
public class ConnSQLite
{

    public System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection Connection;

    public void connect()
    {

        string ConnString = "Data Source=xxx;DataBase=xxx;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;";
        Connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnString);
        Connection.Open();
    }
}
```

what I want is:

the user when login will choose his database and I want to make "DataBase=Tienda;" like this:

```
"DataBase=" + somestringhere + ";"
```

I tries "Application["DataBase"]" doesn't worked

is there another way to make it?

Comment: Nothing to do with your question, but maybe not the best idea to share SA pwd with the world.

Comment: Yep. If that's your real password, you need to immediately change it.

Comment: What kind of application is this? Web? Desktop? This is import to understand the better solution to persist the user's option.

Comment: hi guys this password is in my pc no in my domain...
the application is asp.net web application not desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Take a look to the following use case:**

by the time the user logs in, you can store the selected database into the user session, let's say that you'll have the list of databases into a dropdown and the users picks up whatever the database they want to log in.

```
Session["DataBase"] = dropdown.SelectedValue
```

and then try to use it into your connectionstring

```
public void connect()
{
    string ConnString = string.format("Data Source=APPLE01;DataBase={0};User ID=sa;Password=xxx;", Session["Database"]);
    Connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnString);
    Connection.Open();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't use Application for a user specific setting. Application is global to all users, whereas [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) is specific to a particular user session.

```
//user chooses database, let's say they do this on a page
Session["Database"]=GetUserDatabaseSelection();

//now somewhere else, we'll connect to the database specified by their Session.
public void connect()
{
    string ConnString="";
    switch(Session["Database"])
    {
        case "Tienda": ConnString="Data Source=APPLE01;DataBase=Tienda;User ID=sa;Password=Ases0r1a;"; break;
        case "OtherDB": ConnString="Data Source=APPLE01;DataBase=OtherDB;User ID=sa;Password=myotherpass;"; break;
        default: throw new ApplicationException("Unknown database");
    }
    Connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnString);
    Connection.Open();
}
```